# Suricata logs "A Network Trojan was detected". Is it false positive?

Tags: anti-virus, snort, ids, ips

I use the [Suricata](https://suricata-ids.org/) as IDS on the local network that it doesn't the internet. It logged a few alerts from some clients that said `A Network Trojan was detected`.
All log's properties are in the following:

> **Protocol:** 006
>   **Source:** Client IP
>   **Destination:** Server IP
>   **Signature:** ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For an Executable File in a Temp Directory.
>   **Signature ID:** 1:2025703:2
>   **Category:** A Network Trojan was detected

I have Kaspersky antivirus that updated and also I have Malwarebytes that updated too, however, they hadn't detected any trojans.

**Question:**

Is this a false positive or maybe a real trojan that the antimalware can't detect it?

Server OS: Windows server 2012.
Client OS: Windows 7 and 10.
I use the Suricata default rule.

Comment: There is not enough information to give an answer - it's very possible that it could be a real trojan.

Comment: it's everything that Suricata has logged. Do you know, How can I provide more info?

Comment: Go on client IP, and scan it to see what cause the request, it's the first step to find what it's.

Comment: Thanks, So I'm going to install Wireshark on the client and see what caused the request and I will return to feedback.

Comment: I checked some clients with the Wireshark and I thought the office telemetry caused this log. My network has been having office telemetry to log the Microsoft office activity. So, was that a false positive?